# Can't install Ubuntu Touch on BQ Aquaris E4.5

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, bq

When I try to install Ubuntu Touch on my BQ Aquaris E45 I get the following message:

```
2015/05/10 15:43:03 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...
2015/05/10 15:43:03 Device is |Aquaris_E45|
Device Aquaris_E45 not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/vivid-proposed
```

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap
```

should do the trick

Comment: That's the command I used and it gives me this error again:

2015/05/11 12:15:57 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/05/11 12:16:36 Device is |1|
Device 1 not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en

Comment: Have you put the device into fastboot mode first?  power+vol-up until you see a menu select fastboot and then run the command.  If this is the android version of the bq device though you may need to look to bq to see how to install it correctly first and then upgrade from there.

Comment: Yes, i put the device into fastbood first. On bq website there are instructions to install ubuntu on aquaris e45 usin MTK Flash Tools, I don't use windows so i want to do this on my ubuntu pc

Answer (score 0):

To bring the discussion over from G+:

OP used a special tool provided by MediaTek and bq for the Android version to change the whole internal structure of the phone, e.g. the partition layout, to be compatible with Android.

In this state the phone can no longer run Ubuntu and cannot be used with ubuntu-device-flash.

bq has not released the necessary files to change the phone back to Ubuntu yet, so it's probably necessary to obtain them from bq customer support.

Comment: There was a post with the necessary files, http://www.ubuntugear.com/2015/02/flash-ubuntu-on-bq-aquaris.html